# Contact form with server side validations in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I am trying to make a contact form in angular js. I want to highlight the fields which are not valid in server side validation on clicking submit button.

My HTML code-

```
<form ng-controller="SubmitButtonCtrl">
            <label>STREET ADDRESS</label><br/>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.streetAddress">
            <span>{{user.errorStreetAddress}}</span><br/>
            <label>CITY</label><br/>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.city">
            <span >{{user.errorCity}}</span><br/>
            <label>ZIP CODE</label><br/>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.zipCode">
            <span>{{user.errorZipCode}}</span><br/>
            <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

This my angular js code. I am confused how can I achieve this. Do anyone know a site where I can create forms easily in angularJS.

```
   (function(){
        angular.module('app', [])
        .controller('SubmitButtonCtrl', function($scope, $http){
            $scope.submit = function(){
                $http({
                    method  : 'POST',
                    url     : 'api/getMemberList/',
                    data    : $scope.user, //forms user object
                    headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
                })
                .success(function(data) {
                    if (data.errors) {
                        // Showing errors.
                        $scope.errorStreetAddress = data.errors.streetAddress;
                        $scope.errorCity = data.errors.city;
                        $scope.errorZipCode = data.errors.zipCode;
                    } else {

                    }
                });
            };
        });
    })();
```

Thanks

Comment: have you looked at ng-messages?  That's a pretty good solution to display error messages on forms:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages

Comment: i am not able to update `$scope.errorStreetAddress` `$scope.errorCity` `$scope.errorZipCode` these variables, am i making  2-way binding in bad way???

Comment: you're not binding to the variables you're setting in the success function.  You're setting $scope.error* and then binding to user.error* in the template

Comment: Thanks @Austin your comment worked..

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('yourApp').directive('serverError', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope,element,attrs,ctrl){
      return element.on('change keyup', function(){
        return scope.$apply(function(){
          return ctrl.$setValidity('server', true);
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

[click here](https://solidfoundationwebdev.com/blog/posts/server-side-validation-with-angular-js-rails)